# Quote like "Learn the call of birds and you will never be alone" source?

Tags: quote-source

I read this quote a few years ago and cannot remember the source. I could be misremembering it or combining two quotes together? I just took up birding and this quote is so true: there are not many places (outdoors) that you can be alone from humans and not occasionally hear a bird.

I don't think I adapted it from either of these:

["With birds for company, though I stay away from people, I’m never alone."](https://www.kpcnews.com/columnists/article_b92d875b-07b8-51f0-a9ac-8656ce742975.html) by Neil Case. But this is from May 6, 2020 and I definitely read the quote before then.

["The birds will always sing / And you will never be alone."](https://ninelives.fandom.com/wiki/You_Will_Never_Be_Alone) From a TV show I've never heard of.